# Saving rails text area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a text area that a user can enter text into and when I save it to a database it saves the text exactly as the user enters it.

Example what it saves:

> Test Text
>
> Some more text

I was wondering if you can save it like this instead:

> Test Text \n Some more text

Comment: internally it is saved with `\n`

Comment: Really? When I go to pgAdmin to check the value it shows as just white space is that just pgAdmin showing it that way?

Comment: Have you tried checking in the rails console?, it should be `"Test Text\r\n\r\nSome more text"`.

Comment: check `raw` and `sanitize` if you want to allow some specific tags and discard others

Comment: I checked it in the rails console and it does have \r where the spaces are. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backtick (`) symbol instead of '
For example:

```
$(button).html(`<p> Test Text </p>  
<p>TESTTTTTTT</p>`);
```